# In Python, how would you have a GUI up constantly, but have it constantly fetch data from database to update in real time?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, scheduler, tk-toolkit

The idea I want to accomplish is to have my GUI shown below to always be displayed, but to have the code below always updating and pulling from the database to update the GUI in real time as new information is added or deleted.

I was thinking making the GUI components first, then have the pulling and adding of the information from the db in a function, where I have a `schedule.every(1).minutes.do(getMedinfo)`
to constantly do that function. It does it every minute, but no GUI is displayed.

I know the db works fine, because if I add new information, it gets added but I have to re-compile. Any ideas on how to have the GUI always up with the code adding and deleting real time? Thank you in advance

```
def getMedinfo():

    initialxPlacement = 0.05
    initialyPlacement = 0.32

    initxPlaceNext = 0.56
    inityPlaceNext = 0.32

    for i in medicationSchedule:
        timeTaken = i['TimeTaken']
        dayTaken = i['DayTaken']
        medName = i['MedicationName']
        medNames = Label(text= medName + " taken every " + dayTaken + " at " + converttwentyfourhour(timeTaken) , background = "#1e3f66", foreground = "white", font = "Arial 10 bold")
        medNames.place(relx = initialxPlacement, rely = initialyPlacement, anchor = 'w')

        # Figure out if the pill drops today
        isDay = isDayOfWeek(dayTaken)

        if isDay == 1:
            label =  Label(text= medName + " taken every " + dayTaken + " at " + converttwentyfourhour(timeTaken) , background = "#1e3f66", foreground = "white", font = "Arial 10 bold")
            label.place(relx = initxPlaceNext, rely = inityPlaceNext, anchor = 'w')

        initialyPlacement += 0.05
        inityPlaceNext += 0.05

# def getUserInfoScreen():

# Begin Initial Window
window = Tk(className = 'Magic Meds')
datelabel = Label(background = "#1e3f66", foreground = "white", font = "Arial 15 bold")
timelabel = Label(background = "#1e3f66", foreground = "white", font = "Arial 15 bold")


user = GetUserData.userdata()
date = GetUserData.getSystemDate()
timel = GetUserData.getSystemTime()

user = GetUserData.userdata()
medicationSchedule = GetUserData.getMedications(str(user["_id"]))
amountOfMeds = len(medicationSchedule)

# greeting.place_forget()
# A.place_forget()
# canvas.place_forget()
# canvas.place(relx=0.62, rely=0.004)

usersName = Label(text= user['FirstName'] + " " + user['LastName'] + "s " + "Pill Schedule", background = "#1e3f66", foreground = "white", font = "Arial 15 bold")
usersName.place(relx = 0.455, rely = 0.1, anchor = 'center')

medBox = Canvas(window, width = 765, height = 365, background = "#1e3f66", highlightthickness=2, highlightcolor = "#c66156")  
medBox.place(relx=0.02, rely=0.2)

getMedinfo()


weeklySched = Label(text= "Weekly Schedule", background = "#1e3f66", foreground = "white", font = "Arial 15 bold")
weeklySched.place(relx = 0.22, rely = 0.25, anchor = 'center')

upNext = Label(text= "Pill(s) Dropping Today", background = "#1e3f66", foreground = "white", font = "Arial 15 bold")
upNext.place(relx = 0.74, rely = 0.25, anchor = 'center')

schedule.every(1).minutes.do(getMedinfo)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(10)
```

[GUI Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWxK8.png)

Comment: What is `schedule.every(1).minutes.do(getMedinfo)`

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a function that does the query and updates the display.
2. write a function that calls that function every minute.

It looks something like this:

```
def do_update():
    <your code to fetch the data and update the display>

def run_every_minute():
    do_update()
    root.after(60000, run_every_minute)
```

And, of course, you have to start `mainloop`. After you call `run_every_minute()` once, it will continue to run every minute. There are many, many examples of this pattern on this site. Search for "animation" or "timer" or "clock".

Note: this strategy only works if `do_update()` takes less than a few hundred milliseconds. If it takes longer, you'll probably want to fetch the data in a separate thread or process. Most databases can do a query plenty fast enough.